# Node.js Officegen assign color to cell for a generated excel

Tags: node.js, excel

I am using [officegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen) to generate excel sheet which is downloaded on the user's computer. I want to assign color to certain cells (mostly first cell in each row, based on certain condition) and assign color to the entire rows based on some other condition.

I went through the documentation but I was unable to find any documentation or code on how this can be done. I am not even sure if this is supported in officegen.

Does anyone have any knowledge or experience on how this can be done?